# nesting each functions in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor for running basic sanity tests on a webpage.

In one page there are five tabs and inside the **third one (index=2)** there are three more tabs.

I have written the following code to go through each of them in the order.

The reason for the **if(index!=1)** is that the page loads on to the second tab.

The code is consoling the elements inside the second **if** block.

But is not executing the second **"each"** command.

What am i doing wrong here?.

I need the browser to stick to the third main tab and then go through the nested tabs and then move on to the fourth main tab.

```
it('going through the sub tabs in manage page', function(){

        expect(element.all(by.css('.settingsTabs li a')).count()).toBe(5);
        element.all(by.css('.settingsTabs li a')).each(function(element, index) {
            if(index!= 1){
                element.click();
                browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                browser.sleep(3000);
            }
            if(index == 2){
                console.log(element.all(by.css('.ng-isolate-scope ul li a')));
                element.all(by.css('.ng-isolate-scope ul li a')).each(function(element1) {
                    element1.getText().then(function(text) {
                        console.log(text);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually.

There was two mistakes that i made.

One was the locator and the other was the naming of variables.

Since i am nesting each functions i have to declare different variable names as parameters.

In my case I named them all "element" which was the root cause of all these trouble.

The fixed code is given below:

```
element.all(by.css('.settingsTabs li a')).each(function(elem, index) {
      if(index!= 1){ // here i named the passed argument "elem" 
        elem.click();
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
      }
      if(index == 2){
        expect(element.all(by.css('.tab-pane li a')).count()).toBe(3);
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('.tab-pane li a')).each(function(elemen) { // here it is "elemen"
          elemen.click();
          browser.driver.sleep(2000);
          elemen.getText().then(function(text) {
          console.log(text);
          });
        });
      }
      if(index == 3){
        expect(element.all(by.css('.diagnostic-options li')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
      }
    });
```